# I removed const keyword still it is showing const error in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, model, constants

```
state:

class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  AuthenticationState._({
    this.status = AuthenticationStatus.unknown,
    this.user = EmpVerifyEntity.empty, //----- error in this line
  });

  AuthenticationState.unknown() : this._();

  AuthenticationState.authenticated(EmpVerifyEntity user)
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.authenticated, user: user);

  AuthenticationState.unauthenticated()
      : this._(status: AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated);

  AuthenticationStatus status;
  EmpVerifyEntity user;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, user];
}

Model class:

@JsonSerializable()
class EmpVerifyEntity {
  @JSONField(name: "access_token")
  late String accessToken;
  late EmpVerifyEmployee employee;

  EmpVerifyEntity();

  factory EmpVerifyEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      $EmpVerifyEntityFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => $EmpVerifyEntityToJson(this);

  static var empty = EmpVerifyEntity(); //----this is what I'm calling----------------//

  @override
  String toString() {
    return jsonEncode(this);
  }
}

@JsonSerializable()
class EmpVerifyEmployee {
  @JSONField(name: "password")
  late String password;
  late String avatar;
  @JSONField(name: "_id")
  late String sId;
  @JSONField(name: "emp_name")
  late String empName;
  @JSONField(name: "emp_id")
  late String empId;
  late String designation;
  @JSONField(name: "__v")
  late int iV;

  EmpVerifyEmployee();

  factory EmpVerifyEmployee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      $EmpVerifyEmployeeFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => $EmpVerifyEmployeeToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return jsonEncode(this);
  }
}
```

Here I showed Authentication state and model class where I got error, I removed all const keyword which I used but still it is showing an error in that line which I called empty.how to clear this const error.

error name -the default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
---------------Thank you----------------------------................

Comment: Have you tried like this: `static var empty = const EmpVerifyEntity();`?

Comment: Still it is showing an error

Comment: what if you do `static final empty = EmpVerifyEntity();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with

```
static var empty = EmpVerifyEntity();
```

is that this basically allows it to be overwritten from anywhere in your code by doing

```
EmpVerifyEntity.empty = ...
```

Therefore I think it should help to declare it instead as

```
static final empty = EmpVerifyEntity();
```

This ensures that it can't be overwritten